LaunchedEffect(true) vs LaunchedEffect(Unit)
I'm working on implementing MVI using compose.
as per documentation if we need something to be done once like collecting flow results then do it in LaunchedEffect(true) but, I've found that it's suspicious as per docs.

Warning: LaunchedEffect(true) is as suspicious as a while(true). Even though there are valid use cases for it, always pause and make sure that's what you need.

So, I looked for replacement to avoid this warning and found some using LaunchedEffect(Unit) while LaunchedEffect scope is getting cancelled and restarted if the key is changed.
so, my questions are:

when to use LaunchedEffect(true) and LaunchedEffect(Unit)
when will be both restarted? ( Unit & true )
can I depend on them for loading data first time instead of having isDataLoaded flag?


They are basically the same and produces the same behaviour. Yes, you can use them to load data first time as passing true/Unit as key which will not change instead of a key that changes which will also cause the side effect to restart.

so, that means no way fro restarting the unit/true, am i right?
what about the warning can we ignore?

Please explain in more detail what you need the LaunchedEffect for and what exactly happens in its lambda. LaunchedEffect(Unit) (or true) is most likely not what you want.

Dear @Leviathan I'm asking general Qs to understand them not related to specific cases.
in other terms, at least I need to know differences between both.

The important part of the LaunchedEffect parameter is that it is used to re-execute the lambda when it changes. Since neither Unit nor true will ever change, it doesn't matter which one you provide.
That said, this usually isn't what you want: Everything that the LaunchedEffect accesses from outside its lambda can potentially change therefore needs to be passes as a parameter (instead of Unit or true) so the LaunchedEffect can be executed again, when that changes.
If you provided Unit or true as a parameter to only execute the LaunchedEffect once, this won't work either, because it will still be executed again, f.e. on configuration changes like device rotations.
Any initialization logic is better located in the view model.

what you mean by having the initialization logic in viewModel?
if we will load screen details through api should we do it in viewModel init block better that doing it in LaunchedEffect(true)?

That's right, everything that is not directly UI related shouldn't be part of a Composable. You should structure your app in individual layers with clearly defined responsabilities. For more, see here: https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture

what if i need to do logic related to UI and API call will differ depend on items visibility should i separate them? the UI do in compose and then fire event for calling API or in this case do both in compose side?

Composables should only concern themselves with displaying data and handling user interaction. If additional data is needed it must be requested from the view model, never directly fetched from some API. When new data is available the view model will update the exposed state so your composables can display it. More architectural recommendations like this can be found here: https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/recommendations

noted, thank you so much

Glad to help. If this answered your question you can accept it by clicking the checkmark left of it.

upvote Q if you see it's valid too
